# c# - LINQ select from Collection

Tags: c#, linq, visual-studio-2010

I'm attempting to write a simple `Select` method on a class that inherits from `IList`.

```
public class RowDataCollection : IList<RowData> {
  private List<RowData> rowList;

  internal RowDataCollection(List<RowData> data) {
    rowList = data;
  }
  // ...
}

public RowDataCollection Rows;

public RowDataCollection Select(string colName, object value) {
  List<RowData> rowList = from item in Rows
         where item[colName].Value == value
         select item;
  return new RowDataCollection(rowList);
}
```

Some problems I'm having:

**First:**

- VS2010 reports `Cannot implicitly convert type 'IEnumerable<RowData>' to 'List<RowData>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)`

OK, where does the CAST go?

**Second:**

- Someone could pass in an invalid `colName` value (i.e. `String.IsNullOrEmpty(colName)`) or a null parameter `(object value == null)`.

How would I handle the way my function returns if the input parameters are invalid?

**[Solved]**

I edited my `Select` statement (even renamed it per the suggestions here). I had to use a switch to cast to the data type that the data was in, but it does work.

```
public RowDataCollection SelectRow(string colName, object value) {
  if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(colName) && (value != null) && (0 < Rows.Count)) {
    switch (Rows[0][colName].GetValueType()) {
      case TableDataType.Boolean:
        return new RowDataCollection(Rows.Where(r => (bool)r[colName].Value == (bool)value).ToList());
      case TableDataType.Character:
        return new RowDataCollection(Rows.Where(r => (char)r[colName].Value == (char)value).ToList());
      case TableDataType.DateTime:
        return new RowDataCollection(Rows.Where(r => (DateTime)r[colName].Value == (DateTime)value).ToList());
      case TableDataType.Decimal:
        return new RowDataCollection(Rows.Where(r => (Decimal)r[colName].Value == (Decimal)value).ToList());
      case TableDataType.Integer:
        return new RowDataCollection(Rows.Where(r => (int)r[colName].Value == (int)value).ToList());
      case TableDataType.String:
        return new RowDataCollection(Rows.Where(r => r[colName].Value.ToString() == value.ToString()).ToList());
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

**[Solved (short version)]**

Jon Skeet posted this about the same time I posted my solution, and (as always) his code is much nicer.

```
public RowDataCollection SelectRow(string colName, object value) {
  List<RowData> rowList = Rows.Where(r => r[colName].Value.Equals(value)).ToList();
  return new RowDataCollection(rowList);
}
```

@Jon Skeet: If I ever see your face in the same line at some software developer position I'm applying for, I'm just going to turn around and go home.

*@Everyone*: Thanks for all the help!

Comment: LOL... four exact same answers with @Jon Skeet posting an answer 16 seconds ahead of @sixlettervariables who posted 2 seconds ahead of @Justin Niessner who was 16 seconds ahead of @alexanderb... SO is amazing...

Comment: Something makes me think I'm missing some vital piece of the puzzle to making this LINQ work. I just haven't seen an explanation yet that clicks with me. It's **VOO-DOO** I tell ya!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The result of a query like that isn't a `List<T>`, it's an `IEnumerable<T>`. If you want to convert that into a `List<T>`, just call `ToList`:

```
List<RowData> rowList = (from item in Rows
                         where item[colName].Value == value
                         select item).ToList();
```

As it happens, you're only calling `Where` in your query. I would rewrite this as:

```
List<RowData> rowList = Rows.Where(item => item[colName].Value.Equals(value))
                            .ToList();
```

I'd also rename the method to something which is obviously *filtering* rather than *projecting*, given that the latter is the more common use of the term "select" in LINQ.

As for input parameters - I suggest you validate the arguments and throw an exception if they're not valid:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(colName))
{
    throw new ArgumentException("colName");
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to debug LINQ? It seems to be returning all rows and the column I'm searching on has distinct values.

Comment: @jp2code: It's not really clear what you mean... but for LINQ to Objects, you could always put a break point in the lambda expression.

Comment: I can look at my data and see that there is only one row with an ID of 102, for example. Including the values, `Rows.Where(item => item["ID"].Value == 102).ToList();` is returning everything in my `Rows` collection. This is hard to explain on SO.

Comment: @jp2code: It really *won't* do that. I suspect you're misunderstanding your code, or you're looking at the wrong collection, or something like that. Honestly, `Where` does work :)

Comment: OK, the `IEnumerable<RowData>` returns everything, but (upon closer inspection) `.ToList()` returns nothing. I've added an equivalent C# `foreach` loop, and I can see where `r[colName].Value == value`, but the compiler evaluates that to false. Is that because I am passing in an `object` when the actual data type is an `int` (i.e. `(int)102 != (object)102`)?

Comment: @jp2code: Uh, yes, that would be it... it'll be boxing the value, and then comparing by reference. I've edited the answer to use Equals instead, and that should be okay.

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly cast an `IEnumerable<RowData>` to a `List<RowData>`, however, there does exist a convenience function `Enumerable.ToList<T>()`, used like so:

```
List<RowData> rowList = (from item in Rows
                         where item[colName].Value == value
                         select item).ToList();
```

As for your second question, an exception would occur during the `ToList()` call as the LINQ expression is evaluated immediately. You have a few options, including throwing `ArgumentException`s or returning an empty list. It depends on your use cases. I'd suggest simply throwing an exception (assuming you have some `HasColumn()` method on your `RowData` class):

```
if (colName == null)
{
    throw new ArgumentNullException("colName");
}
else if (!Rows.All(row => row.HasColumn(colName)))
{
    throw new ArgumentException("No such column " + colName, "colName");
}
```

Per your edit, another approach, if a column missing is not necessarily a "problem":

```
...
// note the change to Any()
else if (!Rows.Any(row => row.HasColumn(colName))
{
    throw new ArgumentException("No such column " + colName, "colName");
}

List<RowData> rowList = (from item in Rows
                         where item.HasColumn(colName)
                            && item[colName].Value == value
                         select item).ToList();
```

Comment: `RowData` contains `HasColumn` now! :)

Answer (score 1):

You're getting the error message because LINQ Queries return IEnumerable, not List.

If you need a List, it's easy enough:

```
List<RowData> rowList = (from item in Rows
                         where item[colName].Value == value
                         select item).ToList();
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to convert IQueriable<> to List<>, by calling ToList();

```
  public RowDataCollection Select(string colName, object value) {
      List<RowData> rowList = from item in Rows
             where item[colName].Value == value
             select item;
      return new RowDataCollection(rowList.ToList());
    }
```

Comment: VS2010 puts my *red squiggly line* under the `where` clause!

Comment: -1 the `Enumerable.ToList<T>()` is being called too late. @jp2code: the result of a *raw* LINQ-to-Objects query is `IEnumerable<T>` where `T` is type of the last statement. In your case this is `select item`, and `item` is `RowData`. Hence, `rowList` is `IEnumerable<RowData>` not `List<RowData>`.